# Azcopy psts getting error 404 attempting to upload

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, pst, azcopy

I have been struggling to get pst files uploaded to my azure storage. I have talked with Microsoft support on the phone, at length, and it just feels like guesswork from their end so I thought I would try here.

I have the Office 365 business essentials package. The domain that the current Exchange 2010 Server is on is a .local domain, so I am abandoning it in favor of our new .com domain. I already have O365 configured with the new domain. We only have 15 users so I figured pst files would be the simplest way to do it. This is also my first time using Office 365 and Azure so I have been attempting to follow MS procedures wherever possible.

The issue is whenever I run the azcopy.exe command with my parameters, I get an error 404 not found. Here is the command I am using (I’ve changed a few elements of this command in case I accidentally give away any personal data.):

```
azcopy.exe /source:C:\psts /Dest:"https://f47hr7hfh74hf4747fh74fh74.blob.core.windows.net/ingestiondata?sv=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
randomnumbersletteretc" /V:c:\365uplog\log1.txt
```

Here is the resulting error:

> Error parsing destination location "https://f47hr7hfh74hf4747fh74fh74.blob.core.windows.net/ingestiondata":
>   Failed to validate destination: One or more errors occurred. The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The specified
>   resource does not exist.

Comment: What's the version and permission of your SAS (the sv and sp in your query string)? If your sv is 2012-xx-xx, There is a known issue in the latest version of AzCopy which can't well handle those old SAS, to work around this, you need to update the tool or library to generate your SAS. If your sv isn't 2012-xx-xx, could you share the sp in your SAS? Try to add LIST and READ permission to your SAS may be able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue! I uninstalled the new version and reinstalled from an older version of the AZcopy tool "MicrosoftAzureStorageTools.msi" and it is now working correctly. It looks like an issue with the new client.

Version 5.0.0 works and 5.1.0 looks to be having issues.